Gradle daemon in flutter
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Could not find method android() for arguments [build_dmepgp895ht0fq6d1wyshbi8q$_run_closure1@1e0de42b] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
running the flutter app on physical mobile device

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
